# Unable to update branch.io link using branch.io API

Tags: branch.io

I am facing issue  while updating existing branch link.
Following is my request:

```
{
    "uri": "https://api.branch.io/v1/url/?url=https://example.in/xawwaqse&branch_key=key_live_branchKey",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "json": true,
    "method": "PUT",
    "body": {
        "data": {
            "slug": "test-slug",
            "type": "collection",
            "$desktop_url": "https://www.example.com/test-slug/",
            "$android_url": "https://www.example.com/test-slug/",
            "$ios_url": "https://www.example.com/test-slug/",
            "$og_image_url": "imageUrl",
            "$og_title": "Collection by test | example",
            "$og_description": "Description",
            "$canonicalUrl": "https://www.example.com/test-slug/"
        },
        "branch_key": "key_live_branchKey",
        "branch_secret": "secret_live_branchKey"
    }
}
```

In response, getting following error message:

```
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: OL3HPGV2UBBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJGFSKS4MH0242JIJD)"
}
```

Comment: did you ever work this out, I am experiencing the same issue, and it also does not work if I use `api2.*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few pointers about this request:
 1. Use the updated v2 API as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#link-update)
 2. Replace https://example.in/xawwaqs by a valid URL, i.e. the URL link that you want to eat
 3. Replace key_live_branchKey with a valid value from your Branch Dashboard
 4. Replace secret_live_branchKey with a valid value from your Branch Dashboard
 5. Replace https://www.example.com/test-slug/ by a valid URL

For any further questions, feel free to write to integration@branch.io with the updated cURL.